# Images, OCR and greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, captcha

I have a webpage on which I'm doing tons of cool stuff using greasemonkey. I'm actually pretty terrible at `greasemonkey/javascript` but I'm learning quick. Every once in a while I get a really terrible CAPTCHA validation which I want to automate. I have a command-line utility that can do this with local and remote files, but not with the file in question because It's behind a session..

```
tim@g2sv ocr-thingy my-image.png
135189
```

Works like a charm. I'm looking for a way to pass the image from the website (running the script) to the utility. I don't care how complicated it has to be, but at the moment I'm clueless. I've been thinking about providing the utility as some type of REST-like API for greasemonkey to interface with but I don't know how to supply an image to an API other than by passing the URL which doesn't work (as stated before). Greasemonkey (luckly) doesn't allow you to download a file an run software on my PC so the most straightforward option is out.

I'm open to all suggestions it's a fun side-project for me so the crazier the better `;)` I would prefer an option that silently runs in the background (doesn't take or require focus like mouse and keyboard controlling software, java robot).

**Maybe you're interested to know** I'm not trying to brake any laws or anything, the owner of the website knows I'm doing this and was interested to see if I was able to do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I don't care how complicated it has to be, but at the moment I'm clueless."

Well, it's possible, but it is an "involved" process.  Here's the high level steps:

**Approach 1:**

- Forget about Greasemonkey; write a Firefox add-on.  Add-ons can interact with the file system and probably can get the image data without having to use *Flash* or [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial).

**Approach 2:**

- Use Greasemonkey and JS to send the image data to your server (using [GM_xmlhttpRequest()](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest)).  This is not simple, [search around for how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/934012/331508).
- Your server can be your own local machine running something like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) or any one of the free web-application servers.
- Your server uses PHP (or Coldfusion, or C#, or Python, etc.) to run your OCR program and do whatever you want with the results, including AJAXing them back to the GM script.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far<3. I've thought about the second Approach myself. I know how to use GM_xmlhttpRequest, XAMPP and PHP. But how do "send the image" with the httprequest. If I simply pass the URI to the image to the "API" I won't be able to retrieve the image because the http server doesn't have a session to the website.

Comment: There are questions here on SO that discuss that.  I don't have them bookmarked, but start with ["Get image data in Javascript"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/934012/331508).

Comment: Thanks I think I know enough to continue!